# Why is Eigenvalue different from Variance.percent?

Tags: pca, survey, likert, eigenvalues

[image]I am conducting PCA analysis on results from a Likert-scale (10-point base) survey on user preferences. When using the code below, I obtain the list of variables with their respective eigenvalues. However these eigenvalues are different from the adjacent column which shows variance.percent (in the reference guide, it's one-tenth of the eigenvalue.
Could anyone explain why this might be or if there is anything off with my approach?

```
res.pca <- PCA(mydata, graph = FALSE)
print(res.pca)
library("factoextra")
eig.val <- get_eigenvalue(res.pca)
eig.val
```

Comment: I think it might have to do with the set number of variables. The model seems to be cut at then variables but I have thirteen.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is OK. Sum of eigenvalues is always equal to number of variables (10 on the left and 13 on the right). So `variance.percent` is always `eigenvalue` divided by number of variables.

Comment: Thank you very much.